# Multiple controls with same bindings in single xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a xaml with a `TabControl` with two tabs. Each of the `TabItems` has a `treeview` which has exactly the same code. The bindings, VM etc are exactly same. They work of different data which is handled in my Model depending upon a property. So my VM and View do not need to worry about it.

Is there any way that I can write my `treeview` and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` once and each tab refers instead of duplicating code in the same xaml?

Something like

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <Grid>
           <!-- Refer to the tree view here -->      
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <Grid>
           <!-- Refer to the tree view here -->      
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

But then How to write the `treeview` and `HierarchicalDataTemplate`  and then refer them?

Comment: create two different properties of your ViewModel and bind it your TreeView.

Comment: Just create a UserControl that wraps your treeview and use it in both tab controls

Comment: Do you mean in another xaml? Is there a way to do it in the same xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `DataTemplate` that contains your `TreeView` layout and then use `ContentPresenter` or `ContentControl` to present it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeTemplate">
        <Your TreeViewLayout ...>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...    

<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TreeTemplate}" />   
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TreeTemplate}" />     
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer as it is a misuse of ContentControl. ContentControl's are best reserved for situations where that part of the UI can change dynamically based on some type of binding. The correct answer to this question should be the use of a UserControl.